# Application Verifier stops when calling joyGetPos, joyGetPosEx or joySetCapture

Tags: windows

I'm using the Microsoft Application Verifier (AppVerifier) to validate my executable which uses the Multimedia Joystick API.

Running my program in the debugger, it breaks with the following message on any of the called mentioned in the title (joyGetPos,  joyGetPosEx or joySetCapture).

> VERIFIER STOP 00000303: pid 0xBF8: NULL handle passed as parameter. A valid handle must be used.

Is there anything I can do to fix this other than not using this API?
(I understand, it's pretty old and obsolete, but I could not find MSDN documentation stating it explicitly).

I have an wired Xbox 360 controller plugged in.

Note that the code works. It's just the application validation that fails with AppVerifier.

Comment: Just improve you code.  Don't call these functions when joyGetNumDevs() returns 0.

Comment: I do, and I have a controller plugged in.

Comment: Then AppVerifier probably sees gummy code inside the joystick api.  It is ancient.  Nothing much you can do but temporarily disable the calls I guess.

Comment: What does the call stack look like?